# inline-block display content in divisions from top

Tags: html, css

I need to display these list elements starting from top, I don't want them to be stacked to bottom of container.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4EWrp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
vertical-align: top
```

Answer (score 1):

just add a `vertical-align: top` to your `div.bar`

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}

.bar {
  width: 90px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li>-------</li>
      <li>-------</li>
      <li>-------</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li>-------</li>
      <li>-------</li>
      <li>-------</li>
      <li>-------</li>
      <li>-------</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li>-------</li>
      <li>-------</li>
      <li>-------</li>
      <li>-------</li>
      <li>-------</li>
      <li>-------</li>
      <li>-------</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, if you don't want their to be space between the two elements, you should remove any whitespace between the two `inline` elements: `</li><li>`